# How to keep user inputs within corresponding text fields after segue [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, segue, user-input, viewcontroller

I have two view controllers, first view containing "user form" for inputs and second to display the final results. Everything seems to be working fine, i.e. I can send the final results using "prepareForSegue" function (see below)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var SecondVC: SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
    SecondVC.receivedDP_Summary = summaryDP
    SecondVC.receivedDC_Summary = summaryDC
    SecondVC.receivedDP_CA_Summary = summaryDrillPipe_CsgAnnulus
    SecondVC.receivedDC_CA_Summary = summaryDrillCollar_CsgAnnulus     
}
```

However, as soon as I return to first control view after initialising segue, all the user inputs disappear. Is there any way to store the user inputs within the respective text field so they can be manipulated to see varying results?

I am still very new to programming, so I will really appreciate any help

Comment: Are you setting the UI text to nil or empty strings in any view controller lifecycle calls beside viewDidLoad (viewWillAppear:, viewWillDisappear, etc)?

Comment: Your statement ***return to first control view after initializing segue*** sounds suspicious. You need to navigate back to the previous view controller. If you are initializing a new segue to the previous view controller, you are not coming back but going to a new instance of the view controller.

Comment: Perfect.. thanks alot for the tip... I was using button for segue which like you mention would have caused new instance to generate. I added the nav bar and everything seems to be working fine...